# how to change display format in MVC view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the part of the code in MVC view file cshtml. The iD
is an integer number. It displays like 1 22 333, how can I make the display to 000001 000022 000333.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.iD)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `DisplayFor`use the model

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
     <td>
        @item.iD.ToString("000000")
     </td>
  </tr>
}
```